# And Engine polygons

Tags: android, andengine, polygon

I´m using AndEngine for a game development and my problem is that I don´t know how exactly I should set a polygon body to a sprite.

I tried code mentioned here http://www.andengine.org/forums/gles1/complex-collision-surface-t5593.html#p24822 but no success.

Is there any other way how to make it work? I also attach my code:

```
if (type.equals(ObjectType.STAIRS)) {
            final BodyDef bodyDef = new BodyDef();
            bodyDef.type = type.bodyType;
            bodyDef.position.x=5;
            bodyDef.position.y=5;
            final Body mBody = body;


            PolygonShape pol1 = new PolygonShape();
            Vector2[] vertices = {//rectangular
                    new Vector2(0,
                            -sprite.getHeight() * 0.5f),//top right
                    new Vector2(-sprite.getWidth() * 0.5f,//top left
                            -sprite.getHeight() * 0.5f),
                    new Vector2(-sprite.getWidth() * 0.5f,//bottom left
                            sprite.getHeight() * 0.5f),
                    new Vector2(0,//bottom right
                            sprite.getHeight() * 0.5f) };
            pol1.set(vertices);
            fixtureDef.shape = pol1;
            mBody.createFixture(fixtureDef);            
            pol1.dispose();


            final PolygonShape pol2 = new PolygonShape();
            Vector2[] vertices2 = {//triangular
                    new Vector2(0,
                            -sprite.getHeight() * 0.5f),//top
                    new Vector2(0,
                            sprite.getHeight() * 0.5f),//left
                    new Vector2(sprite.getWidth() * 0.5f,
                            sprite.getHeight() * 0.5f),//right
                    };
            pol1.set(vertices2);
            fixtureDef.shape = pol2;
            mBody.createFixture(fixtureDef);
            pol2.dispose();
            body=mBody;
```

Answer (score 1):

I finally solved this problem using PhysicsEditor and it´s loader: http://www.codeandweb.com/physicseditor

Answer (score 0):

looks like you didn't use get width scaled and pixel to meter ratio constant to make it in to meter.

need to use physics connector to register the body to the sprite I think...